# Show consent screent only once , google Oauth

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm integrating my app with google Oauth sign in,

Everything works great, but I don't want that google shows the consent screen every single time a user is trying to access my app, I just want to show it the first time and after that as long the user has not cleared its cache just ask for its email and password without shows one more time the consent screen.

Comment: Do you have some code you can share? It's hard to answer without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: If your not already doing so I would switch to decorators. It should do what you are asking. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

Comment: You need to be requesting and storing a refresh token for each user.